# Is it necessary to restrict google api key when app server is communicating securely with it

Tags: android, api, security, ssl, google-api

## Background

I was in the process of getting a new api key for my backend application that communicates with google maps api, does some computation with it then provide it's own api end point(s) that can be consumed by our mobile client apps:
 [image]

The clients communication with my backend is not secure, however when I call the endpoint from google api, it's through ssl:

```
    'directions' => [
                    'url'      => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/',
                    'type'     => 'GET',
                    'key'      =>  null,
                    'endpoint' =>  true,
     ..
```

However, it seems that google strongly recommends protecting your key from being stolen by malicious 3rd parties:

[image]

## Question

If only my backend server talks to the google api endpoint through a secure channel, would it still be necessary to restrict the api key to certain endpoints (if we ignore the possibility of an inside job theft)?